# Error on client side when install run project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports, dataset

I have developed a window based project that is my first project and I am using crystal reports to print but after installation on the client side, when i run the report then it is showing an exception that is

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
at BARTAN_STORE.DataSets.BalanceSheet.InitClass()
```

Can you tell me how to solve this exception.

Comment: Have you made sure that the proper Assemblies/ .DLL's are in the Bin folder ? or you can GAC the .DLL's for Chrystal Reports. please confirm what you have or have not tried.. thanks

Comment: Now i have add the Assemlies

Comment: What does the .config file look like..? what version of .NET did you compile this project / Install in..? what version of .NET is installed on your machine or the target machine if there is one..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Happening because on your client system those dll are not registered

You need to copy that assembly (.dll) to your project folder and make sure that you should add the reference from the new location in that project.

I was having the same issue.

Comment: This will add those dll in installation process and put them to the client system

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the version (Target framework) of your project, in application section

1. Right clic on your project
2. Select the properties section
3. Update Target  Framework on application section